# What does '=>' mean?

Tags: c#, lambda

What does `=>` means? Here's a code snap:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { trace.Add(response); }));
```

Comment: Also, the example you are looking at makes it very difficult to understand what the Lambda operator does. See some of the example below and in the links below.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want '

Comment: I think this question will spark lots of answers that have similar meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's lambda expression which is the simplified syntax of anonymous delegate. it reads 'goes to'. equivalent to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() { trace.Add(response); });`

Answer (score 2):

=> is lambda expression operator which indicate that the code is lambda expression.

```
( param ) => expr(int x) = > { return x + 1 };
```

or

```
param => exprx=> x + 1;>
```

**What is Lambda expression ?**

```
* Lambda expression is replacement of the anonymous method avilable in C#2.0 Lambda 
  expression can do all thing which can be done by anonymous method.
* Lambda expression are sort and function consist of single line or block of statement.
```

Read more : [Lambda Expressions](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/11/lamda-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

=> is an operator called Lambda Operator

It is used for creating a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's the [lambda operator =>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is a lambda operator which reads like "goes to"

Answer (score 0):

This "=>" means the use of lambda expression syntax in C#.

This syntax is available since Visual Studio 2008 in .NET 3.5 (C# 3.0). This is the [MSDN official documentation of lambda expression in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

The code above is the same as anonymous delegate in already available since C# 2.0

Your code:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { trace.Add(response); }));
```

is translated into:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new delegate () { trace.Add(response); });
```

Those two codes essentially have the same semantics.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that a single expression lambda doesn't need the {} around the body, nor does it need a semicolon, so you can simplify your code (slightly) to.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => trace.Add(response) ));
```